# pm2 app in symlink'd directory yields 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a node.js application configured to run via `pm2` in a directory structure like this:

```
/opt/project/v1/web/index.js
/opt/project/current -> /opt/project/v1
```

That is, *current* is a symlink to *v1*. I need `pm2` to start the app in *current/web*, not in *v1/web*.

I first did this:

```
cd /opt/project/current/web
pm2 start index.js
```

The web site ran fine, but `pm2` resolved the symlink to */opt/project/v1/web/index.js*. So I found [this forum thread about `pm2` resolving symlinks](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1663), and from there I tried this instead:

```
cd /opt/project
pm2 start current/web/index.js
```

The process appeared to start, and `pm2` showed it in the list and showed the symbolic path, except visiting the page now yields a 502 (Bad Gateway) error.

The output of `pm2 show` for that last attempt is:

```
┌───────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────┐
│ status            │ online                                │
│ name              │ index                                 │
│ restarts          │ 7                                     │
│ uptime            │ 2s                                    │
│ script path       │ /opt/project/current/web/index.js     │
│ script args       │ N/A                                   │
│ error log path    │ /root/.pm2/logs/index-error-0.log     │
│ out log path      │ /root/.pm2/logs/index-out-0.log       │
│ pid path          │ /root/.pm2/pids/index-0.pid           │
│ interpreter       │ node                                  │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                                   │
│ script id         │ 0                                     │
│ exec cwd          │ /opt/project                          │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                             │
│ node.js version   │ 6.8.1                                 │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                     │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                     │
│ created at        │ 2016-12-03T22:08:58.972Z              │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Thinking that perhaps the different cwd was a problem, I then tried this, also from that thread:

1. Create a file *app.json*:

   ```
   {
    "apps": [
       {
         "name": "index",
         "script": "index.js",
         "args": [],
         "watch": true,
         "node_args": "",
         "merge_logs": true,
         "cwd": "/opt/project/current/web",
         "env": {
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Start with `pm2 start app.json`

When I did it this way the results were the same as the previous attempt except `pm2` showed the correct cwd, but still got a 502.

None of the log files seem to show any errors and pm2 shows the app as online.

I really don't know anything about node.js or `pm2`, I was handed an existing system and tasked with reorganizing the file system a bit. I have a very basic working knowledge of `pm2`'s commands now, but that's about it.

So my question is: How can I get the app to run in the symlink'd path and why does it respond with a 502 when I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. I solved it by using this configuration file (saved as app.json):

```
{
    "apps": [
    {
        "name": "index",
        "script": "./index.js",
        "cwd": "/opt/project/current/web",
        "exec_mode": "fork_mode",
        "env": {
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

And starting it like:

```
cd /opt/project
pm2 start current/web/app.json
```

And it worked like a charm, although I'm not sure exactly which difference here solved the problem, I didn't take the time to investigate further.